Conditional Expectation for a multivariate normal distribution
I have $n$ random variables, $X_1, ..., X_n$, with covariance matrix, $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{n\times n}$ and I am trying to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_1 | X_2 = x_1, ..., X_n = x_n)$.
I am aware of the bivariate case:
$$\mathbb{E}(X_1 | X_2 = x) = \mu_1 + \rho_{1,2} \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(x - \mu_2).$$
From Wikipedia:
$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 \\ \mathbf{x}_2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{with sizes} \quad \begin{bmatrix} q \times 1 \\ (N-q) \times 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\text{and accordingly } \boldsymbol{\mu} \text{ and } \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \text{ are partitioned as follows}
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{with sizes} \quad \begin{bmatrix} q \times 1 \\ (N-q) \times 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{11} & \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \\ \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{21} & \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22} \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{with sizes} \quad \begin{bmatrix} q \times q & q \times (N-q) \\ (N-q) \times q & (N-q) \times (N-q) \end{bmatrix}
$$
giving:
$$
\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}} = \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} (\mathbf{a} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_2)
$$
Then would I be making $q=1$? Which results in $$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} = \begin{bmatrix} \rho_{1,2} &  \rho_{1,3} & ... & \rho_{1,n} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22} = \begin{bmatrix} \rho_{2,2} &  \rho_{2,3} & ... & \rho_{2,n}\\ 
\rho_{3,2} & \rho_{3,3} & ... & \rho_{3,n}\\
 ...& ... & ... &  ... \\
\rho_{n,2} & \rho_{n,3} & ... & \rho_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1} = \mu_1$$
$$\boldsymbol{\mu}_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \\ ...\\ \mu_n \end{bmatrix}$$
And the observations:
$$\boldsymbol{a} = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ x_3 \\ ...\\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$$
Then I plug into $\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}}$?

Hi: you need the matrix relations rather than the univariate relation.  Once you have the matrix  relation, the extension to whatever number of variables is just making the four $\Sigma$ matrices so that they always correspond to what you're conditioning on. I'm not explaining this very well but if you read this, you'll see what I'm trying to say. https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mvn-cond.html

@markleeds I have made an update to the post

exactly. The covariance matrix is always a 2 by 2 matrix of $\Sigma$ elements. The question is what the dimension of those matrices are and that only depends on the length of the two original vectors. So, I don't know if you used the link but I  think you get it now.

Note that there's also a formula for the variance of the conditional multivariate normal that you will need also in order to obtain the complete distribution of the conditional.
